# Cmake can't find the cuda.h file

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

My project only has source files with extensions like *.cpp or *.h. But some of them call cuda host functions and use the cublas library. After using `enable_language(CUDA)`, the cmake can find nvcc in the configuration phase:

```
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 8.0.61
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /gpfs/share/software/cuda/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /gpfs/share/software/cuda/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -- works
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
```

However, when compiling these source files, I got this error:

```
fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
```

And the compiler selected by cmake is still /usr/bin/c++ not nvcc. How to deal with this error? Must I rename these sources file to `.cu` and `.cuh`?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to include the CUDA headers with `include_directories()`. Should be from the `CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable.

It's perfectly fine to have C++ files using CUDA headers, but you need to add the includes as for any other library.